# Serialise and deserialise javascript obj

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace `'{"name":"32\" TVs"}'` by `'{"name":"32\\" TVs"}'` .

`'{"name":"32\" TVs"}'` is the output produced by:

```
const obj = [{ 
    "name": '32" TVs'}];

const str = JSON.stringify(obj);

console.log(str); // outputs '{"name":"32\" TVs"}' on the console.
```

Tried `variableName.replace(/[\"]/g, '\\"')` but it produces `'{\\"name\\":\\"32\\" TVs\\"}'`.

**Founded**: '\"' is considered as the single char.

**Use case of serialization and deserialization:**

*1). Server side*=>

```
const obj = [{ 
    "name": '32" TVs'}];

const str = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(str); // produces => '[{"name":"32\" TVs"}]'
```

and this string is being passed to the client

*2). Client side*=>

```
const str = '[{"name":"32\" TVs"}]';
const parsed = JSON.parse(str);// throws SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 14
```

More complex javascript object which I want to serialize and deserialize:

```
const obj = [
    {
        "name": "Men's Fashion"
    }, {
        "name": "32\" TVs",
        "seourl": "store/stationery-essentials  ",
    },
    {
        "name": '32" TVs'
    }
];
```

here we have the special characters (i.e. one of the ", ', \t) within the values.

**Founded that**: variableName.replace() considers ", \", \t as a single character.

Could you please help about how can we serialize and deserialize this javascript object?

Comment: You should be using a capture group `/(\\")/g` and not `[]`. Make your full replace function this way: `.replace(/(\\")/g, '\\"'))`.

Comment: The \ must also be escaped in the replacing string.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman why would you use a capturing group here ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret To replace it. Isn't it? If I am wrong, can you clarify, sorry?

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman You do not need capturing groups around the whole pattern when replacing. If you need to refer to a whole match, use `$&` backreference.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: `// throws error` What error? What does it say?

Comment: How is that string passed to the client? Can you show us that logic?

Comment: creating javascript on the server using Jade and returning to the client. Ultimately client has const str = '[{"name":"32\" TVs"}]'; in the script tag, and I'm not able to back purse this string.

Comment: @SandeepSharma: Then that JavaScript is created incorrectly. It should generate `const str = '[{"name":"32\\" TVs"}]';`.

Comment: JSON.stringify(obj); // produces => '[{"name":"32\" TVs"}]' Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @SandeepSharma: You say your ___Jade___ backend generated that JavaScipt. Show us that. The problem is in there, because of how escape characters work in strings.

Comment: @Cerbrus Could you please tell, why stringify() is producing /' instead of //", I checked the consoled output and the number of chars in the generated string, both are same.

Comment: @SandeepSharma: did you look at my answer, after the updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the square brackets ([character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)), they match a single instance of any character in the brackets.

Also, escape your backslashes:

```js
const str = '{"name":"32\\" TVs"}'; // Escaped slash there to make sure it makes it into the actual string.

console.log("before:", str);
console.log("after:", str.replace(/\\"/g, '\\\\"'));
```

The `'\\\\"'` results in the following replacement string: `\\"`, since it's two excaped backslashes (`\\`) and a `"`.

---

That all said, the problem appears to be in how your client-side JS is generated.

You say your Jade back-end generates the following JS:

```
const str = '[{"name":"32\" TVs"}]';
```

While this is a string, it is not valid JSON. To declare a JS string with an escaped quote in it, you need to escape the escape character:

```
const str = '[{"name":"32\\" TVs"}]';
```

This will result in the following JSON string being stored in `str`:

```
[{"name":"32\" TVs"}]
```

Which can then be parsed:

```js
const str = '[{"name":"32\\" TVs"}]';
const obj = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(obj);

// There isn't a `\` in the `name` property:
console.log(obj[0].name === '32" TVs');
```

Note that this `console.log` will *display* `\"`, but that `\` will not actually be part of the string. It's just shown to tell you that that's an escaped quote in the string, not a string end.

Comment: str is formed by JSON.stringify(). there is only one \ before ". how could I escape this?

Comment: @SandeepSharma: Look at the `"before"` console log line. There is also only one `\ ` in `str`. We need to write two because `\ ` is a special character in JavaScript: It escapes the following character. Try this: `console.log('\\"test\\"'); console.log("\"test\"");`

Comment: This answers the question however you are replacing the `"` too.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: Is that a problem? It seems like the OP wants to replace a _"slash that's followed by a double-quote"_  with a _"double slash followd by a double quote"_. Otherwise, we might end up doubling slashes where they shouldn't be.

Comment: Not a problem, like I said your answer does solve the problem. I am just curious as to why `console.log("after:", str.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\'));` fails, at least when tested on JSFiddle.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: That code doesn't fail in the Chrome dev console. It shows the same output as the one I have in my answer. That's odd...

Comment: Yeah, just tested it again at work and works fine in JSFiddle. Oh well, shouldn't get in front of a computer *too* early in the morning...

Comment: I think the question was not clear, added the use case. Please take a look.

Comment: **Thanks** Cerbus for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! Did this answer answer your question, @SandeepSharma?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

`variableName.replace(/\\"/g, '\\\\"')`

On your original attempt, you was placing both `\` and `"` con a character class. So both characters would be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Cerbrus. You helped me to find the issue. I solved the problem by double stringifying the input on the server side.

```
const obj = [{ 
    "name": '32" TVs'}];

let state = JSON.stringify(obj);

console.log(state);// outputs '{"name":"32\" TVs"}' which is the invalid string.

// We needed to escape special characters (i.e ', ", \t, \', \" etc) 
// that's why need to stringify again.
state = JSON.stringify(state); 

// removing first and last character of the string.
state = state.substring(1, state.length - 1);
```

Now the state is a valid string that needs to be sent to the client.